# How to create a Google Bot friendly robot.txt on a WordPress?

Tags: php, robots.txt, googlebot

I am using WordPress. One of the files `functions.php` contains `function do_robots() {...` which blocks Google crawling. I have replaced this function with the following:

```
function do_robots() {
    header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' );

    do_action( 'do_robotstxt' );

    if ( '0' == get_option( 'blog_public' ) ) {
                     echo  "User-agent: *";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-admin";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-includes";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-content";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /stylesheets";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /_db_backups";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /cgi";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /store";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-includes\n";
    } else {
                     echo  "User-agent: *";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-admin";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-includes";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-content";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /stylesheets";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /_db_backups";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /cgi";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /store";
                     echo  "\nDisallow: /wp-includes\n";
    }
}
```

1. I am not quite sure about `Allow`. Is it that as long as I do not `Disallow`, it is `Allow` by default?
2. Why does Google Bot still get blocked by the above `function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [original function](https://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/functions.php) out of SVN looks like it's blocking fewer paths than your example above, so I would recommend removing some of the extra directories (e.g. wp-content) and seeing if that is what you're looking for.  You could also try the WordPress [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) to generate a Google Sitemap for their engine to read.

```
function do_robots() {
    header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' );

    do_action( 'do_robotstxt' );

    $output = "User-agent: *\n";
    $public = get_option( 'blog_public' );
    if ( '0' == $public ) {
        $output .= "Disallow: /\n";
    } else {
        $site_url = parse_url( site_url() );
        $path = ( !empty( $site_url['path'] ) ) ? $site_url['path'] : '';
        $output .= "Disallow: $path/wp-admin/\n";
        $output .= "Disallow: $path/wp-includes/\n";
    }

    echo apply_filters('robots_txt', $output, $public);
}
```

The rule for `robots.txt` files is that everything is allowed unless specified, though a search engine obeying `robots.txt` is more of a trust system than anything.